# seq24 is connected to zynaddsubfx but I can't get seq24 to play patterns

Tags: 12.10, sound

So I got seq24 to play sounds when I click on the piano roll but when I try to play the pattern nothing happens.  It's running through qjackctl but clicking play in seq24 isnt doing anything. I'm using 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a patched version of seq24 as the version in 12.10 (0.9.2) has a JACK transport issue. Keep an eye on the [KXStudio-Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/ppa), it will soon have a patched seq24 package for Quantal too.

Regards,

Jeremy